# Struts2 debug tag thinks toString() is udefined

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags, freemarker, ognl

Debug tag in Struts2 keeps getting this error. Any ideas what could cause this?

```
FreeMarker template error!

Expression stackObject.value.get(propertyName).toString() is undefined on line 58, column 122 in template/simple/debug.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==&gt; ${stackObject.value.get(propertyName).toString()?html} [on line 58, column 120 in template/simple/debug.ftl]
 in include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/debug.ftl" [on line 23, column 1 in template/xhtml/debug.ftl]
----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Value stack had an object with overridden toString method that returned null.